# Docker documentation - How "filter" option works for container "ls" command?

Tags: docker

Here, https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_ls/,
there is the documentation for the "container ls" command.
You can use the "filter" option and this is all it says about it:

> --filter , -f     Filter output based on conditions provided

Where is it explained how it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker container ls` is the same as `docker ps`, so you can refer to that [documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/ps/) for a comprehensive description of that flag:

> The filtering flag (-f or --filter) format is a key=value pair. If there is more than one filter, then pass multiple flags (e.g. --filter "foo=bar" --filter "bif=baz")

the doc page also shows a list of all supported filters together with examples